# are there tutorials on how to name variables?

Tags: .net, python, language-agnostic, naming-conventions

as you can probably tell from my previous posts i have horrific naming conventions. do you know of any tutorials dealing with how to name stuff?

Comment: previous posts?! your username alone suffices as a commentary on your naming conventions!

Comment: +1! have a great shabbas aaron

Comment: Also, please learn what Hungarian notation MEANS and what it was BASTARDIZED into later. Learn the origins of the Hungarian notation, and why originally it was a nice idea. Then learn that this is the slippery road to a nice religious debate. Ok, Hungarian has been mentioned, let us not dwell on it ;) ~~ Systems Hungarian bad, Apps Hungarian good, as intentions.

Comment: That looks like two consecutive underscores in your username.  That's reserved for the implementation in C++ (and, I think, C).  (Of course, there's a space in mine, so it's not a valid identifier name either.)

Comment: It depends on the language, too. Different languages have different naming conventions. You tagged your question with both `.net` and `python`, so I'm assuming you want the question to be language-agnostic?

Comment: aaron put that in an answer and ill mark it right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the answers here are quite valid. Most important: be consistent.

That said, here are my rules (C#):

- camelCase identifiers -- I personally
  find this much easier to read than
  underscores
- `Public` properties start
  with a capital letter
- Something I
  should never touch starts with an
  underscore -- example, the backing
  field to a property should only be
  touched from the property. If I have
  underscores elsewhere, I know I'm
  wrong
- Apps Hungarian where
  appropriate -- ints describing row
  IDs perhaps could be named
  `rowSelected`, `rowNextUnread`, et
  cetera. This is different than
  Systems Hungarian, which would mark
  them as ints such as `iSelected`,
  `iNextUnread`. Systems Hungarian
  doesn't add much if anything, where
  Apps Hungarian gives information the
  type doesn't: it tells me adding
  `rowItemsPerPage` and `colSelected` is a
  meaningless operation, even though it
  compiles just fine.

Comment: Well, there could be a reason for adding rows and cols, but yes, having the intent presented in the logic makes checking against documentation (or heaven forbid, creating documentation) much much easier. Thank you @Peter Leppert, for encapsulating the rules into something tiny and compact. `hehehe, I still suggest he go read Code Complete, but that's only 'cos it's the answer I gave ;)`

Comment: "camelCaseEverythingIPersonallyFindThisMuchEasierToReadThanUnderscores." camel case everything? seriously?

Comment: I thought the brevity of "everything" would be better than the more technically correct "variable names, method names, class names, namespaces, and any other identifiers" -- I never thought somebody would take it to mean "Full sentences". I meant places where people tend to use underscores or justmashingeverythingtogether. Sorry for being so unclear.

Comment: I find that using 'da kine' is much clearer than 'everything'in such situations http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Da_kine

Answer (score 11):

i will recommend to check this book [image]

[http://www.amazon.com/Code-Complete-Practical-Handbook-Construction/dp/0735619670/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1281129036&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670)

Comment: beat me to it!!! (also: start around page 280 for the variable naming stuff, he gets to it pretty early on)

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there will be any good tutorials, because there aren't any hard-and-fast rules. Here are some tips:

- Conform to convention: Loop variables are `i`, `j`, and `k`; variable numbers of arguments go in `*args` and `**kwargs`; use camelCase or underscored_names.
- Be consistent.
- Be concise. `list_of_drugs_used_in_this_program` is much less clear than `drugs`. Similarly, you don't need to include the datatype of the variable in the name: `drugs_list` is redundant.
- Don't go overboard with the underscores. I've never needed more than one. 2+ is pushing it.
- Never ever *ever* use [metasyntactic variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable) (`foo`, `spam`...) in anything but quick-and-dirty examples. `method1` is also out.

But you could summarise all of that with:

### Don't be silly.

---

Tee hee.

> Variable naming conventions can often
>   turn into a religious war, but I’m
>   entirely confident when I declare The
>   World’s Worst Variable Name to be:
>
> ```
> $data
> ```
>
> Of course it’s data! That’s what
>   variables contain! That’s all they
>   ever can contain. It’s like you’re
>   packing up your belongings to move to
>   a new house, and on the side of the
>   box you write, in big black marker,
>   “matter.”

http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2004/03/the_worlds_two_worst_variable.html

Comment: $data is a perfectly good name for a general-purpose data-handling routine that doesn't know or care what the nature of the data is. It's like what's a poignant love-letter or an angry arrears-notice to you are both just mail to the mail carrier.

Answer (score 5):

1. A bad convention followed fully is better than a combination of different good "conventions" (which aren't conventions at all any more, if they aren't kept to).
2. However, a convention that is making something less clear than if it had been ignored, should be ignored.

Those are the only two I would state as any sort of rule. Beyond that convention preferences are a matter of opinions quickly turning into rants. The rest of this post is exactly that, and shouldn't be read as anything else.

1. For collections, use natural language plurals. In English, this means data, schemata, children, indices, criteria, formulae (and indeed foci, geese, feet, men, women, teeth) not made-up words like datums schemas, childs, indexes, criterions, formulas (and likewise focuses, gooses, foots, mans, womans, tooths, believe it or not I've actually seen some of those in use). Camel-casing and abbreviatiating does enough damage to English as it is, without doing more. Okay, I've never seen datums, but I have seen the meta-plural datas. Sweet Aradia, why?
2. That said, use American English for names, even if you use a different dialect of English. Most coders with such dialects have learnt to think of "color" as a word for colours in a computer context by the age of 12, and the principle applies more widely. If we can deal with "color" (one of Webster's worse bastardisations) we can deal with -ize and -ization (-ise and -isation is a pseudo-French 18th C affectation anyway, the Americans are the traditionalists on this one).
3. Similarly, if you aren't sure how to spell a word that you are using as the whole or part of a name, look it up (google it and see what google says). Somebody may spend a long time distracted by your misspelling that is so liberally distributed throughout running code as to make fixing it daunting.
4. Hungarian is bad (in many modern languages, though in some it has its place) but the principle is good. If you can tell a const, static, instance, local and parameter variable from each other in a split-second, that's good. If you can tell something of the intent immediately, that's good too.
5. Related to that, _ before public variables makes them non CLR compiant. That's actually a good thing for private variables (if you make them public for a quick experiment, and forget to fix the visibility, the compiler will warn you).
6. Remember Postel's Law, "be conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from others". One example of this is to act as if you are using a case-sensitive langauge, even if you're using a case-insensitive one. A related one is to be more of a stickler in public names than private ones. Yet another is to pay more attention to following conventions well than to complaining about those who don't.

Answer (score 3):

Not a tutorial... more like a guide/best practice kind of thing:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(VS.71).aspx

Comment: additionally http://weblogs.asp.net/scottdockendorf/archive/2005/01/26/361020.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend purchasing a copy of "Clean Code" by Robert C. Martin. It is full of great suggstions ranging from naming conventions to how to write easy-to-understand functions and much more. Definitely worth a read. I know it influenced my coding style since reading it.

Answer (score 3):

hi for me you should always put the most explicit names:

```
string_to_hash = "blabla"
hash(sring_to_hash)
```

and respect the [pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide. You code should then be very easy to read.

Answer (score 3):

There are many different views on the specifics of naming conventions, but the overall gist could be summed up as:

> Each variable name should be **relevant**
>   to whatever data is stored in the
>   variable.
>
> Your naming scheme should be **consistent**.

So a major no-no would be
single letter variables (some people
use i and j for indexing loops, which
is OK because every programmer knows
what they are. Nevertheless, I prefer
'idx' instead of 'i'). Also out are
names like 'method1', it means nothing
- it should indicate what the variable holds.

Another (less common) convention is the 'Hungarian' notation where the data type is prefixed to the variable name such as 'int i_idx'. This is quite useless in modern, object oriented programming languages. Not to mention a blatant violation of the DRY principle.

The second point, consistency, is just as important. camelCase, UpperCamelCase, whatever - just don't switch between them for no reason.

You'll find that naming conventions vary from language to language and often, a company will have their own rules on naming.

Its a worthwhile investment to properly name your variables because when you come to maintain your code much later on and you have forgotten what everything means, it will pay dividends.

Comment: As somebody else pointed out, the 'Hungarian notation' you point out here is not the (useful) practice originally conceived -- look for Systems vs Apps. Wikipedia even has a full section devoted to it.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify what language are you looking for. Since your question is flagged .NET, here is a document I follow when writing  C# code: http://weblogs.asp.net/lhunt/pages/CSharp-Coding-Standards-document.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read Code Complete? He does a full treatise on this in the book. Definitely the best naming strategy I've seen in print... And it's easy to find like 1000 programmers at the drop of a hat who name this one of the top 5 resources for programmers and program design.

Just my $.05

Answer (score 1):

Can I make a shameless plug for the "Names" chapter in my book, "A Sane Approach to Database Design" ? I'm specifically talking about names for things in databases, but most of the same considerations apply to variables in programs.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if your question relates to Python naming conventions.

If so, for starters I would try to follow just these simple rules:

- `ClassName` - upper case for class names
- `variable_name` - lower case and underscore for variables (I try to keep them at two words *maximum*)